# SQL count of differences of specific timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table that looks like this:

```
UNIQUEID    FILEKEY DTTMSTAMP
-------------------------------------------
282           1     2012-07-19 09:02:00.000
283           1     2012-07-19 17:12:00.000
284           1     2012-07-20 08:53:00.000
285           1     2012-07-20 17:09:00.000
286           1     2012-07-23 08:54:00.000
287           1     2012-07-23 17:06:00.000
288           1     2012-07-24 09:00:00.000
289           1     2012-07-24 17:04:00.000
290           1     2012-07-25 08:59:00.000
291           1     2012-07-25 17:05:00.000
```

There are well over 50K rows. I need to get the following info out of this:

I need the count of the number days where there are exactly 4 timestamps for a given `filekey` and the difference between the fourth `dttmstamp` and the 3rd `dttmstamp` is greater than 3 hours.

It should ultimately look like this:

```
Filekey   Count 
----------------
1         650
```

etc.

Comment: `exactly 4 timestamps` do you mean the same day?

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, pls rephrase and/or add the realistic desired output.

Comment: You have presented us with 10 rows of sample data and a count of 650. You also mention 3rd and 4th timestamp. What does that mean? 3rd and 4th indicate an order, what is the order? As posted currently this just doesn't have enough detail for us to help.

Comment: exactly 4 timestamps on the same day.  As mentioned above, there are over 50K rows of data, I just included a few to show the structure.  By the 3rd and 4th stamps, I meant the latest on a given day and the 2nd latest stamp.  In the many rows of data, there are many different filekeys, all numerical.  a sample out put would then be:

Comment: Filekey: 1, Count: 650; Filekey: 2, Count: 237; Filekey: 3, Count: 114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  FILEKEY,
            DTTMSTAMP,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FILEKEY, CAST(DTTMSTAMP as date) ORDER BY DTTMSTAMP) as RN,
            DATEDIFF(second,LAG(DTTMSTAMP,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY DTTMSTAMP),DTTMSTAMP)/3600 as SEQ
    FROM YourTable
)

SELECT  FILEKEY,
        COUNT(DTTMSTAMP) as [COUNT]
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 4 and SEQ >= 3
GROUP BY FILEKEY
HAVING MAX(RN) = 4
```

For SQL Server < 2012 this should work in `cte` part:

```
SELECT  t.FILEKEY,
        t.DTTMSTAMP,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.FILEKEY, CAST(t.DTTMSTAMP as date) ORDER BY t.DTTMSTAMP) as RN,
        DATEDIFF(second,DTTMSTAMP_PREV,DTTMSTAMP)/3600 as SEQ
FROM YourTable t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 DTTMSTAMP as DTTMSTAMP_PREV
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE FILEKEY = t.FILEKEY AND DTTMSTAMP < t.DTTMSTAMP
    ORDER BY DTTMSTAMP DESC
    ) as d
```

Comment: Very close but you also need to test MAX(RN) = 4

Comment: Wow... just found out this is SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @Green well... The `outer apply` part should work well. If so, put it into instead of `cte` from second query. Like `FROM (query) as c`

Comment: @gofr1 - Apparently with CTE as came in 2008, I'm stuck with SQL-server 2000.  Any thoughts?  also would like to know how to get count of days where 1st and 2nd stamps difference is >= 5 and 4 stamps on a given day

Comment: @Green use sub-query, instead of cte. Just change where part, instead 4 use 2, instead 3 use 5.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 onwards:

```
with CTE as
(
select FILEKEY, 
       convert(date, DTTMSTAMP) as DTSTAMP,
       DTTMSTAMP, 
       datediff(hh, DTTMSTAMP, lead(DTTMSTAMP) over(partition by FileKey order by DTTMSTAMP)) as Dif,
       row_number() over(partition by FILEKEY order by DTTMSTAMP) as R_ORD
from MyTable
)

select FileKey, count(distinct DTSTAMP)
from CTE
where exists (select 1 from CTE a where a.Filekey = Filekey and Dif >= 3 and R_Ord = 3)
group by FileKey
having max(R_Ord) = 4
```